# How to call non-crud Stored Procedure from Entity Framework Code First

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a simple stored procedure that takes no parameters and returns zero for success.

How do I wire that up using Code First so that I can call it from the Context?

When using an edmx (Database First) you can use the wizard to import a function and then call it on the Context:

```
Context.MyStoredProcedure();
```

Is there a way to do this with Code First?

I have found many examples but they are all CRUD type of stored procedures.

Greg

Comment: You might want to expand your question to include examples of said stored procedure, and what didn't work for you.

Comment: @BoltClock Thks, I have expanded the question.

Answer (score -1):

While I thought that there would be a specific mapping for a stored procedure on the context, the following is the only way I could find for Code First Development:

```
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("EXEC ClearLog");
```

Comment: In addition please note that self-answered questions are held up to a somewhat higher standard, in particular because you're contributing both the question and the answer.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I have updated the answer to make this as clear as possible.